# Is there an equivalent rdbms rownums in cassandra(cqlsh or cassandra python module) for pagination without predicate condition in cqlsh

Tags: python, cassandra, pagination, datastax, cql

Is there an equivalent rdbms rownums in cassandra for pagination without predicate condition to traverse to the whole table and fetch the rows and operate on them.

I was trying to operate on a huge table which has millions of rows with primary key a,b and I need to purge records based on timestamp column which is column c

I have tried using Limit in cqlsh and also with python modules, I have used fetch_size feature in cassandra python module but was not successful to implement pagination. Will need your advice to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `token` function. This [link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/paging_c.html) may help you.